# Pydantic: how to extract schema from nested dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I have a dictionary with database configurations (key `databases`)(`ServiceDatabase` and `OtherDatabase`) and want to extract it into two different submodels inside. Example:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict
from typing import *

from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class ServiceDatabase:
    connect_string: str


@dataclass
class OtherDatabase:
    connect_string: str
    service: str


@dataclass
class PydConfigurator:
    """ Instead of the forward assignment as below, 
    I want implementation with Pydantic options or field or 
    any other object 
    """
    databases: List[Union[ServiceDatabase, OtherDatabase]]

    service_db: ServiceDatabase = None
    other_db: OtherDatabase = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.service_db = self.databases[0]
        self.other_db = self.databases[1]


data = {
    "databases": {
        "service_db": {
            "connect_string": "postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}"
        },
        "other_db": {
            "connect_string": "postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}",
            "service": "Any"
        }
    }
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Example usage:
    config = PydConfigurator(**data)
    assert asdict(config.service_db) == data['databases']['service_db']
```

And I want to implement it with Options or Schema functional of pydantic.
In my mind it would be something like `service_db = Field(schema=ServiceDatabase, extract_from='database')`

Comment: Can you try being more clear about what you want? Can you give expected inputs/outputs? It looks like you might be trying this?: `settings_db = SettingsDatabase(**sources['databases']['service_db'])`

Comment: Ok, I will update it with working example (but in another way)

Comment: Afraid I'm still not exactly sure what you're asking, best to give a self contained and complete example of the problem. My suspicion is that what you need is a `@validator('service_db', always=True)` which populates `service_db` from another field.

Comment: I updated working example and I hope that it will be more self-explanatory